# Spring-boot: Required request part 'file' is not present

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, multipartform-data, multipart

I receive error `Required request part 'file' is not present` when I want to upload pictures.
I intend to upload videos and images. Video upload works well but images won't work.
Here is my code.

Spring-boot

```
  @ApiOperation(value = "Post new file")
  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                 @RequestParam (value = "accesstoken", required = true) String accessToken,
                                 RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws Exception{
      tokenService.verifyAdmin(accessToken);

      storageService.store(file);
      return "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
  }
```

StorageService.store

```
  @Override
  public void store(MultipartFile file) {
      try {
          if (file.isEmpty()) {
            throw new StorageException("Failed to store empty file " + file.getOriginalFilename());
           }
           Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), this.rootLocation.resolve(file.getOriginalFilename()));
      } catch (IOException e) {
  throw new StorageException("Failed to store file " + file.getOriginalFilename(), e);
     }
  }
```

Html - image upload

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="date01">Cover Image</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <button class="btn-primary" name="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-max-size="2MB" ngf-select="ctrl.uploadCoverImageFile($file)">Upload</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Html- video upload

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="date01">Upload video</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <button class="btn-primary" ngf-select="ctrl.uploadVideoFile($file)">Upload</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
self.uploadCoverImageFile = function(file){
     self.upload(file,-1);
};
self.uploadVideoFile = function(file){
    self.upload(file,1);
};
self.upload = function (file,x) {
    fileUploadService.uploadFile(file).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp);
    }, function (evt) {
        if(x > 0)
            self.videoUploadProgress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        else
            self.coverimageUploadProgress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
    });
};
```

FileuploadService.uploadFile

```
//ng-file-upload: [https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload]
uploadFile: function(file){
        return Upload.upload({
            url: baseEndPoint + '/',
            data: {file: file, accesstoken: userService.accesstoken}
        });
    },
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="500000000000"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

AppConfig.java

```
@ImportResource("classpath:/vod/config/config.xml")
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think to enable `multipart`: I had the same problem, I just added the following propertiy to the .properties file:

```
multipart.enabled=true
```